# Graph API Get Full List of Azure AD Groups

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get a full list of every group in Azure AD. I am currently able to get 999 records with the following uri:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$top=999`

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) from Microsoft there are only a couple OData query parameters available, none of which appear to be able to navigate to the next page. It also states the maximum page size is 999. I have tried using the `$skip` parameter to skip a certain number of records, but it is not supported:
`{"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"'$skip' is not supported by the service.",...`

Is there any way to get a full list of all AAD groups? We have several thousand that I would need to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some queries against Microsoft Graph return multiple pages of data either due to server-side paging or due to the use of the $top query parameter to specifically limit the page size in a request. When more than one query request is required to retrieve all the results, Microsoft Graph returns an @odata.nextLink property in the response that contains a URL to the next page of results.

For example, the following URL requests all the users in an organization with a page size of 5, specified with the $top query parameter:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$top=5

If the result contains more results, Microsoft Graph will return an @odata.nextLink property similar to the following along with the first page of results:

You can retrieve the next page of results by sending the URL value of the @odata.nextLink

ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

Answer (score 0):

With `$top`, you can customize the result size within the range of 1 and 1000. Because of your question, I guess that 1000 is exclusive, so the range goes from 1 to 999 (inclusive). Read more about the query parameter `$top` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter). I got the range information from [List messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

The response you get from [List groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) seems to not contain `@odata.nextLink` which you would normally expect in such a case, so `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups` does not support pagination. That would also explain why you get an error if you try to use `$skip`. You can read more about `$skip` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#skip-parameter).

In order to get the full list of **all** groups, I would stop using the query parameter `$top`.

Comment: Because of the accepted answer of @vicky kumar, it seems that pagination is indeed supported (not explicit noted in the provided docs link). Then you can of course use `@odata.nextLink`.