# Azure GraphServiceClient limits results to 100, how to get all (C# .NET Core)?

Tags: azure, limit, graphserviceclient

I am working on an Azure Function App. It needs to retrieve all groups in Exchange. I am using this simple C#, .NET Core code:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient;
var groups = graphClient.Groups.GetAsync().Result;
```

But, I only get 100 groups. How do I increase this limit to unlimited?

A lot of searching, but no luck.

Comment: Please see if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77428782/get-list-all-users-from-azure-ad/77429168#77429168.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `PageIterator`:

```cs
var client = new GraphServiceClient(credentials);

var page = await client
    .Groups
    .GetAsync();

if (page is null)
{
    return;
}

//the resulting list with all groups
List<Group> groups = []; //or use new() for C# lang versions <12.0

var pageIterator = PageIterator<Group, GroupCollectionResponse>
    .CreatePageIterator(
        client,
        page,
        group =>
        {
            //perform an action on each result
            groups.Add(group);
            //return true to keep iterating
            return true;
        });

await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The PageIterator is a very good way and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the available groups using `$top` query parameter.

- With `$top` parameter, you can customize the result size.
- If the response contains more results, Microsoft Graph will return an `@odata.nextLink` property to list the remaining groups.

**Below is my code Snippet:**

```cs
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
     ILogger log)
 {
     log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    string ClientId = "<Your_Client_ID>";
    string ClientSecret = "<Your_Client_Secret>";
    string scopes = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
    IConfidentialClientApplication pravapp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(ClientId)
        .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
        .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your_Tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token"))
        .Build();
     var authResult1 = await pravapp.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { scopes }).ExecuteAsync();
     string myaccessToken = authResult1.AccessToken;

     String authorizationToken = myaccessToken;
     string token = authorizationToken.ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
     TokenProvider provider2 = new TokenProvider();
     provider2.token = token;
     var authenticationProvider1 = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(provider2);
     var graphServiceClient1 = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider1);
     var group = await graphServiceClient1.Groups.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
     {
         requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 5;
     });
     return new OkObjectResult(group);
 }
```

- This will provide an `@odatanextlink` as shown below:

[image]

**References:**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73203861/19991670
2. [Paging Microsoft Graph data in your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging?tabs=http)